# Does Chakra UI have setFieldsValue function?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd, formik, chakra-ui

ANTD's form has setFieldsValue function.

So I used that function to set my form's default values from api call.

is there any same function in chakra ui?

When rendering the screen for the first time, I hope that the inputs in the form are filled with the values received through the api call.

Chakra UI's documentation recommended to use Formik but is there any better way ?

I know there is a way to do that with Formik's initialValue.

but I'm looking for a better way.

Comment: You could try to take a look at [React Hook Form](https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform) they have a function called `setValue` kinda similar to `setFieldsValue`

Answer (score 0):

The scope of FormControl within Chakra is just to provide some context that will help styling of the form elements, via `isDisabled`, `isInvalid` etc (https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/form-control/props)

In regards to form management, you should use a separate library like `react-hook-form`

With `react-hook-form` you simply `register` your form data directly onto the Chakra form element component, e.g. Input, not the FormControl

```
const {
  register,
} = useForm({
   defaultValues: {
      name: 'Joe Bloggs'
   }
})

...
<Input {...register('name')} />
```

If you are setting default values based on an API, I would recommend fetching the data in the parent component, and only render the component that contains the form when you have the data and have passed it through via props, as defaultValues only get set on the first render of the form.

e.g. using `react-query`

```
function Parent(){
   const { data, isLoading, isError } = useQuery(...)

   if(isLoading) return <Loading />
   if(isError) return <Error />
   
   return <MyForm defaultValue={data}/>
}

function MyForm({ defaultValue }){
   const {
      register,
   } = useForm({
      defaultValues: defaultValue // { name: 'Joe Bloggs' }
   })

   ...
   <Input {...register('name')} /> // <-- value = 'Joe Bloggs'
}
```